# Can not concatenate string with int in purge command

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to say the following:

```
"channel successfully purged, cleared {amount} messages"
```

where `amount` is the amount of messages that have been purged.

But, I've been getting this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

This is the code I have right now:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def purge(ctx, amount):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    asyncio.wait(2)
    await ctx.send("channel successfully purged, cleared {amount} messages")
```

I tried adding `await ctx.send(f"channel successfully purged, cleared {amount} messages")`, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Your error doesn't come from the send but from the `await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)`. Try to replace `async def purge(ctx, amount):` by `async def purge(ctx, amount:int):` to see what is happening.
And `asyncio.wait` needs `await` in front.

Comment: The error indicates that the problem is in a different part of the code, and not in the attempt to format the string.

Answer (score 0):

When a member uses a command and passes and argument, that argument is passed to the function as a string. Thus, `amount`, when the command is invoked, will be a string. So, the fix is to use the `int()` function to get the integer representation of `amount`.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def purge(ctx, amount):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Parameter `<amount>` must be an integer")
        return
    await asyncio.wait(2)
    await ctx.send("channel successfully purged, cleared {amount} messages")
```

The `try`/`except` handles any `ValueError` exceptions which may be raised. One scenario would be if `amount` were a string of a non-integer value, such as `"Hello World!"` or `"1.23"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a purge command myself and let me explain the difference between `amount` your mention and message that are `deleted`. These can not always be same. Just for example, you have 50 messages in the channel and your used this command:

```
!purge 100
```

The bot will obviously just delete 50 messages only but will display 100 as you are directly saying that. But there is a pretty good and easy fix for it.

Also, the error you are getting would be fixed. One more thing, you should rather use:

```
@commands.is_owner
```

Rather than what you are actually using.

This the code I use for my bot.

```
@nd.command() # Clear command
@commands.is_owner()
async def clear(ctx, limit: int, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    clearembed = discord.Embed(title="Clear", description=f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}! I have successfully cleared {len(deleted)} messages from the channel: #{ctx.channel.name}. \n \nReason: {reason}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=clearembed)
```

I gave the `await ctx.channel.purge()` the variable `deleted` and thus when I do `len(deleted)`, it gives out the correct number of messages deleted.

Hope this solves your issue. Please comment down in the post in case you still get any issue.

Thank You! :D